Missing tag for some of pushed images in DigitalOcean Registry
I faced a strange behavior of DigitalOcean Container Registry. I use Github Actions pipeline below. But sometimes some of my images are pushed to container registry without a tag. Analyzed pipeline logs I figured out that image can be pushed without tag in case if exactly this tag is already exist in container registry.
For example:
f6faf32705e0: Layer already exists
cbcc5cc0f927: Pushed
193c61e: digest: sha256:b27f7491309cfac024594e6ba5dbbe70073b09fc98fdb03f5c5fb123bd5c7121 size: 3268

Sometimes pipeline try to push image with the same tag as a previous build (193c61e). In this case this image will be pushed without a tag.
The question is: how to prevent pushing of images without a tag?
Thanks in advance!
pipeline:
name: build

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '**'
  create:
    tags:
      - '*'
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install doctl
        uses: digitalocean/action-doctl@v2
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}

      - name: Log in to DigitalOcean Container Registry with short-lived credentials
        run: doctl registry login --expiry-seconds 12000 --access-token ${{ secrets.TOKEN }} -v

      - name: Check if image exists
        id: check_image
        run: |
          TAG=$(echo $GITHUB_SHA | head -c7)
          if doctl registry repository list-tags app --format Tag | grep -q $TAG; then
            echo "Image with tag $TAG already exists."
            echo "image_exists=true" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          else
            echo "Image with tag $TAG does not exist."
            echo "image_exists=false" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          fi

      - name: Build and push container image
        if: steps.check_image.outputs.image_exists == 'false'
        run: |
          TAG=$(echo $GITHUB_SHA | head -c7)
          docker build -f Dockerfile --tag ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_NAME }}/app:$TAG .
          docker push ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_NAME }}/app:$TAG


You could add a step in your workflow checking if the tag already exists in the registry before pushing it.
